# Как проверить в javascript, чтобы была истинной только одна переменная?

Tags: javascript

```
let a;
let b;
let c;
let d;
```

Как получить `true`, если только одна из четырех переменных `= true`. Если больше одной - `false`.

Comment: Ну например так `(a + b + c + d)===1`

Comment: Хах, впечетляет! А если часть из них undefined, я получу NaN

Comment: преобразуйте в bool перед суммированием

Comment: `(!!a + !!b + !!c +!!d) === 1`

Comment: `[a, b, c, d].filter(a=>a===true).length === 1`

Comment: Немного извращений (в виде конечного автомата с тремя состояниями): `[a, b, c, d].reduce((acc, item) => acc == null ? (item ? item : null) : acc ? !item : false, null)`. :) Единственно, что если все 4 значения `undefined`, то вернется `null`, а не требуемое `false`.